Why are comments being deleted? And by who?
I added a comment to How to change text before and after a specific word in Microsoft Word this morning, after an existing comment from another user asking for clarity.
Both comments have been deleted, but why and by who?

Only moderators and the user themselves can delete a comment. If a comment containing the key words like “thanks” will automatically be deleted when flagged. Ultimately commentary is temporary.

@Ramhound some kinds of flags can also cause comments to be removed if enough people flag it. In which case the deletion is attributed to the last person who flagged.

@Robotnik - I mentioned that fact.

@Ramhound sorry, I missed the word "other". Some other kinds of flags can also remove comments. I meant not just ones on "thanks" comments :)

@Robotnik - I only used that one example. My comment left open to other keywords automatically deleting a comment.

Ah, so - for once, its not our fault. OP asked the question before, re-asked, then self deleted the duplicate question and the comments remain on that original of the duplicate question.
The post with the comments (viewable with 10k+ reputation only) was 8 hours ago, and the one that's there is 21 hours ago.
The princess, or at least your comments, are in another castle.

And here's a screenshot of the deleted comments for reference.

Ok,.so the OP made a mess of it. Thanks for the insight.

And now both questions have been deleted...

Not our fault again :D

Yeah, I see the Author deleted them both. Strange behaviour...
